# Obtaining the string representation of a PyObjectType when raising a Type Error in a Python C Extension

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I am checking the types of user input like so:

```
PyObject *key = PyTuple_GetItem(tuple, 0);
if (!PyObject_TypeCheck(key, &PyBaseString_Type) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Key must be str");
    return NULL;
}
```

However, In the exception message, I would like to include the bad type the user has submitted, to make debugging for him easier.

Is there a simple or otherwise idiomatic way to achieve this?

---

The only way I can think of is the following:

```
PyObject *key = PyTuple_GetItem(tuple, 0);
if (!PyObject_TypeCheck(key, &PyBaseString_Type) {
    // This returns a new reference which must be Py_DECREFed
    PyObject *bad_type_string = PyObject_Str((PyObject *)key->ob_type);
    char *bad_type_char = PyString_AsString(bad_type_string);
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "Key must be str, not %s", bad_type_char);
    Py_DECREF(bad_type_string);
    return NULL;
}
```

Which I suppose I could wrap in a macro:

```
# define CHECK_TYPE(expr, name, input) \
    do {    \
        if (!(expr)) {
            PyObject *bad_type_string = PyObject_Str((PyObject *)input->ob_type);  \
            char *bad_type_char = PyString_AsString(bad_type_string); \
            PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "%s must be str, not %s", name bad_type_char); \
            Py_DECREF(bad_type_string); \
            goto error; \
        }
    } while (0);
```

And used like such:

```
static PyObject *foo(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    // ...
    PyObject *key = PyTuple_GetItem(tuple, 0);
    CHECK_TYPE(PyObject_TypeCheck(key, &PyBaseString_Type, 'key', key);
    // ...
error:
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could slightly misuse [the `PyArg_ParseTuple` mechanism](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#c.PyArg_ParseTuple). The slight bit of non-neatness is that it outputs into a `const char*`, so you have to get the item from the tuple too.

```
const char* out;
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(tpl,"s", &out)) {
    return NULL;
} else {
    key = PyTuple_GetItem(tpl,0); /* borrowed - remember to incref */
}
```

This generates something like

> TypeError: must be str, not int

---

Note: This is fine for Python 2 since `"s"` matches both `str` or `unicode` object (i.e. effectively `basestring`). For Python 3 it will only accept `str` (not `bytes`) so you might have to follow [the documented advice](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#strings-and-buffers) and "to use the `O&` format with `PyUnicode_FSConverter()` as converter." This gives an error of

> TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Additionally, it's a bit nicer because the `out` is a `PyBytesObject` that you can use directly instead of having to do `PyTuple_GetItem`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I meant to ask for a generic solution that could apply to any PyObject, not necessarily a tuple. However you got me thinking, why not continue this like so: `PyArg_ParseTuple(Py_BuildValue("(o)", "s", &out))` - What do you think?

Comment: I think (but I'm not 100% sure) that [`PyArg_Parse`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#c.PyArg_Parse) can take either a tuple or a single argument (based on the description of the old function call method it was designed to be used on). I haven't tested this though